# spring @Aspect not injecting dependencies

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am using compile time weaving using maven, spring and aspectj

my aspectj advisor looks like this

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingInterceptor {
  private LogManager logManager;
  public void setLogManager(LogManager logManager) {
    this.logManager = logManager;
  }
  .....
}
```

My applicationContext.xml look like this

```
<!--configures the AspectJ aspect and indicates which Spring context should be used when giving advice-->
<context:spring-configured />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<!--<context:component-scan base-package="com.reverb" />-->

<bean id="loggingInterceptor" class="com.myapp.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor">
    <property name="logManager" ref="logManager" />
</bean>
```

The logManager is always null....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see your `logManager` to be defined anywhere. Even if it is, `@Aspect`s are not automatically eligible for injection. In fact what happens is that you have 2 objects - one is a bean of type `LoggingInterceptor`, and the other is the aspect, which actually handles the AOP. But the aspect is not a bean.

In order to make this work, you'd need to define `factory-method="aspectOf"` for your `<bean>`. [See here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-configure) for more info.

Comment: I do have logManager, I just didn't write it here. I will test with the factory-method...Thanks

Comment: adding factory-method="aspectOf" fixes that problem

Comment: @Bozho "See here" Link outdated?.

Comment: @Bozho - do you know what the equivalent configuration is using JavaConfig?  I have been unable to figure it out.

Comment: I haven't used java-config, but I guess it should be possible

Answer (score 1):

With java configuration it will be look like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class AspectConfig {
}
```

Don't forget to:

- Add `@Configurable` annotation

on aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Configurable
public class CounterAspect { 
    @Inject
    private CounterService counter;
    //...
}
```

- Add `'org.springframework:spring-aspects'` as compile dependency
- Add `META-INF/aop.xml`

with content:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>   
    <!-- add to debug: options="-showWeaveInfo -verbose -debug"-->
    <weaver>
        <include within="com..*"/>
    </weaver>    
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.your.package.CounterAspect"/>
    </aspects>    
</aspectj>
```

- Enable javaagent with something like `-javaagent:/path-to-aspectj/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar`

Comment: this should be a preferable way nowadays